# Como puedo resolver el error de que no se encuentra el archivo fonts.xml durante la ejecución del archivo jar?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

cuando ejecuto la app en Netbeans, no me muestra ningún tipo de error, pero cuando genero el jar, y lo abro con la consola de windows me muestra el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.jav
> a:124)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFi
> ller.java:89)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFi
> ller.java:104)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFi
> ller.java:62) at
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:   179)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:81)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.
> java:457)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillMa
> nager.java:864)
> at Vistas.frmReporteVentas.cargarReporte(frmReporteVentas.java:258)
> at Vistas.frmReporteVentas.btnAceptarActionPerformed(frmReporteVentas.ja
> va:242)
> at Vistas.frmReporteVentas.access$300(frmReporteVentas.java:22)
> at Vistas.frmReporteVentas$4.actionPerformed(frmReporteVentas.java:102)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
> ce)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
> rivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
> rivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
> rivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.
> engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : fonts.xml
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontF
> amilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:188)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtension
> s(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensio
> ns(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.(JRStyled
> TextParser.java:83)
> ... 48 more
> Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at :
> fonts.xml
> at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInputStreamFromLocation(R
> epositoryUtil.java:159)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontF
> amilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:183)

He buscado pero no consigo resolver el error, el error me da cuando intento abrir un reporte hecho con jasper reports.

Este es el código que uso para mostrar el reporte:

```
private void btn_AceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try {
        castearFechas();
        //File file = new File("src/RPT/VentasGPrecio.jasper");
        //File file = new File("/RPT//VentasGPrecio.jasper");
        //JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/RPT/VentasGPrecio.jasper"));
        String jReport = "C:/tsmanager/reportes/TPU/VentasGPrecio.jasper";
        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(jReport);
        
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put("fecha", Fecha1);
        param.put("fecha2", Fecha2);
        
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, param, c);
        frm.maximizarReporte(jprint, "Ventas TPU");

    } catch (JRRuntimeException | JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Este es el código de la clase "maximizarReporte":

```
public void maximizarReporte(JasperPrint reporte, String titulo)
{
    JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(reporte, false);
    view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    view.setVisible(true);
    view.setTitle(titulo);
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    view.setMaximizedBounds(env.getMaximumWindowBounds());
    view.setExtendedState(view.getExtendedState() | view.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

Comment: ¿Tiene mas texto la excepción? Dice que es una excepción JRRuntimeException  de jasper, pero seguramente detrás vaya el detalle de qué es lo que le ha pasado.

Comment: Ese es todo el mensaje que aparece

Comment: ¿Cómo manejas las [dependencias de Jasperreports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-v6-requirements)?.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de JR estás usando? ¿Dónde está tu carpeta `fonts` y qué hay en ella?